# How to insert data from datetimepicker to ms access using c#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am beginners I am using inserting data from **datetimepicker** to ms access. My code is:

```
    private void SaveSale()
    {
        string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["saledbx"].ConnectionString;
        string cmdString = "INSERT INTO Sale (Date, Sale, Expense) VALUES (@Date, @Sale, @Expense)";

        using(OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connString))
        {
            using(OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdString, con))
            {
                con.Open();

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", TodayDatePicker.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sale", SaleTextBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Expense", ExpenseTextBox.Text);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                MessageBox.Show("Today Sale is added Successfully!", "Sale Saved", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }
    }
```

**I am facing this error:**

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

Comment: You may try to Parse TodayDatePicker.Text to DateTime (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) or retrieve it from datetimepicker, if possible (try TodayDatePicker.Value), and use it instead of string.

Comment: which line is actually throwing the error?

Answer (score 2):

**Date** is a reserved keyword. If you can't change that field's name, then you should enclose it between square brackets

```
string cmdString = "INSERT INTO Sale ([Date], Sale, Expense) VALUES (@Date, @Sale, @Expense)";
```

Next, I suggest to use Add instead of AddWithValue in particular because you are working with dates that are prone to many conversion errors.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", OleDbType.Date).Value = TodayDatePicker.Value;
```

In this way you can tell your database engine the exact datatype of the parameter passed and avoid any conversion from string to datetime values